# DNN Website not running method correctly on one computer

Tags: server, dotnetnuke

So I have a DNN Website, there is a feature in the site that updates a users table when you click a button. I wrote this feature, and it works on my local machine and on the webserver, it works for everyone except for my client. My client is running windows 8.1 and the latest version of firefox and chrome. I'm really stumpped on how it can be running fine on my computer when I look at the webserver, but not on their computer when they are looking at the same webserver. When they click the button for the method in question the webpage just refreshes to the default page load rather than going to the correct page and adding new data to the table, even after the button is clicked I will check the database and there is no change. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Are they logged in when performing this action?